# Undefined reference errors installing GRASS addon

Tags: grass-gis, add-ons

I am trying to install the `r.geomorphons` GRASS addon (available from http://sil.uc.edu/pdfFiles/jarek/r.geom.zip) in GRASS. I tried on Windows but gave up and decided the best thing to do was to try on an installation of the OSGEO Live CD, as I assumed that would have everything nicely configured. I have installed the Live CD to a virtual machine, and tried following the instructions at http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Compile_and_Install#Addons.

There doesn't appear to be a `configure` script in the directory, so I have simply run `sudo make MODULE_TOPDIR=/usr/lib/grass64`. I also tried various other versions of this command, including some setting the `GRASS_HOME` directory, but all of them give lots of errors saying `undefined reference`. I assume somehow I am not including the GRASS libraries properly.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

The errors I get are:

```
user@osgeolive:~/build/r.geom$ sudo make MODULE_TOPDIR=/usr/lib/grass64 GRASS_HOME=.
/usr/lib/grass64/include/Make/Module.make:25: warning: overriding commands for target `install'
/usr/lib/grass64/include/Make/Rules.make:90: warning: ignoring old commands for target `install'
gcc -L/usr/lib/grass64/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--export-dynamic -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/lib/grass64/lib    -o /usr/lib/grass64/bin/r.geomorphon OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/geom.o OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/main.o OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/memory.o OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/pattern.o  -lgrass_raster.6.4.2 -lgrass_pngdriver.6.4.2 -lgrass_driver.6.4.2 -lgrass_gis.6.4.2 -lgrass_datetime.6.4.2 -lz     -lfreetype    -lgrass_gis.6.4.2 -lgrass_datetime.6.4.2 -lz     -lpng  -lz  -lm  -lgrass_psdriver.6.4.2 -lgrass_driver.6.4.2 -lgrass_gis.6.4.2 -lgrass_datetime.6.4.2 -lz     -lfreetype    -lgrass_gis.6.4.2 -lgrass_datetime.6.4.2 -lz      -lgrass_driver.6.4.2 -lgrass_gis.6.4.2 -lgrass_datetime.6.4.2 -lz     -lfreetype    -lgrass_gis.6.4.2 -lgrass_datetime.6.4.2 -lz      -lgrass_gis.6.4.2 -lgrass_datetime.6.4.2 -lz     -lm  -lm  -lz 
OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/main.o: In function `main':
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:84: undefined reference to `G_add_keyword'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:85: undefined reference to `G_add_keyword'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:86: undefined reference to `G_add_keyword'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:157: undefined reference to `Rast_window_rows'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:158: undefined reference to `Rast_window_cols'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:159: undefined reference to `Rast_get_window'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:163: undefined reference to `Rast_row_to_northing'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:163: undefined reference to `Rast_row_to_northing'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:229: undefined reference to `Rast_open_new'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:230: undefined reference to `Rast_allocate_buf'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:245: undefined reference to `Rast_is_f_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:252: undefined reference to `Rast_set_c_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:255: undefined reference to `Rast_set_f_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:258: undefined reference to `Rast_set_d_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:334: undefined reference to `Rast_put_row'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:343: undefined reference to `Rast_close'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:344: undefined reference to `Rast_short_history'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:345: undefined reference to `Rast_command_history'
/home/user/build/r.geom/main.c:346: undefined reference to `Rast_write_history'
OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/memory.o: In function `get_cell':
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:44: undefined reference to `Rast_is_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:45: undefined reference to `Rast_set_f_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:51: undefined reference to `Rast_is_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:52: undefined reference to `Rast_set_f_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:58: undefined reference to `Rast_is_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:59: undefined reference to `Rast_set_f_null_value'
OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/memory.o: In function `open_map':
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:12: undefined reference to `G_find_raster2'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:17: undefined reference to `Rast_open_old'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:18: undefined reference to `Rast_get_cellhd'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:19: undefined reference to `Rast_map_type'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:25: undefined reference to `Rast_allocate_buf'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:29: undefined reference to `Rast_allocate_buf'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:30: undefined reference to `Rast_get_row'
OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/memory.o: In function `shift_buffers':
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:75: undefined reference to `Rast_allocate_buf'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:82: undefined reference to `Rast_get_row'
OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/memory.o: In function `write_form_cat_colors':
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:103: undefined reference to `Rast_init_colors'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:106: undefined reference to `Rast_add_color_rule'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:110: undefined reference to `Rast_write_colors'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:111: undefined reference to `Rast_free_colors'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:112: undefined reference to `Rast_init_cats'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:114: undefined reference to `Rast_set_cat'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:115: undefined reference to `Rast_write_cats'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:116: undefined reference to `Rast_free_cats'
OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/memory.o: In function `write_contrast_colors':
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:135: undefined reference to `Rast_init_colors'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:138: undefined reference to `Rast_add_d_color_rule'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:142: undefined reference to `Rast_write_colors'
/home/user/build/r.geom/memory.c:143: undefined reference to `Rast_free_colors'
OBJ.i686-pc-linux-gnu/pattern.o: In function `calc_pattern':
/home/user/build/r.geom/pattern.c:26: undefined reference to `Rast_row_to_northing'
/home/user/build/r.geom/pattern.c:27: undefined reference to `Rast_col_to_easting'
/home/user/build/r.geom/pattern.c:46: undefined reference to `Rast_is_f_null_value'
/home/user/build/r.geom/pattern.c:50: undefined reference to `Rast_row_to_northing'
/home/user/build/r.geom/pattern.c:51: undefined reference to `Rast_col_to_easting'
/home/user/build/r.geom/pattern.c:75: undefined reference to `Rast_row_to_northing'
/home/user/build/r.geom/pattern.c:76: undefined reference to `Rast_col_to_easting'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/lib/grass64/bin/r.geomorphon] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module r.geomorphon has been written for GRASS 7 (as I can see from the used functions) while the OSGeo Live DVD offers GRASS 6.

Two options:

- install GRASS 7 (that may even work on the OSGeo Live DVD, then the module
- modify the code to use the GRASS 6 functions, see [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Grass7/RasterLib/ListOfFunctions)

Concerning Windows: if you convince the author to upload the code to the GRASS Addons SVN repository, Windows executables will be autogenerated every night for it.

Comment: That's great - thanks. Is there some information on how to add to the GRASS Addons SVN repository somewhere - I could then direct the author to it and hopefully it'll happen.

Comment: Sure! May I ask where you have looked (URL)? Then I'll add the link there, too, for easier orientation. Will also post it here of course.

Comment: I looked at http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/DownloadSource, which seemed to give a SVN repository address and implied that you needed an OSGeo user account to get access, but I was wondering whether there was a kind of tutorial 'How to add your addon to the repository' guide?

Comment: OK, on that page is "Subversion GRASS Addons source code repository". I have added now there "Want to contribute? Read on here" with "here" pointing to http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/HowToContribute#WriteaccesstotheGRASS-Addons-SVNrepository